# Join table as array in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to join a result from a sub select as JSON, but am having difficulties figuring out how to.

I have the following query:

```
select books.* from libraries inner join books on libraries.id = books.id
```

I'd also like to join the results from another table as JSON.

For that I'd like to use something like

```
select row_to_json(page) from (select * from pages) page
```

I'd like to achieve results where each row has the book columns, the library columns and pages are represented as a JSON column. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `books` related to `pages`?

Comment: Each book row has a page_id and each page_id has a book row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want page id as an array of jsonb objects. I think just aggregating the page id as an array might be a good alternative.

```
SELECT
  libraries.id,
  books.id,
  JSONB_AGG
  (
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT
    (
      'id', pages.id
    )
  ) AS page
  FROM libraries
    INNER JOIN books ON books.id = libraries.id -- books.id really matches libraries.id?
    INNER JOIN pages ON pages.book_id = books.id
  GROUP BY
    libraries.id,
    books.id;
```